# How can I print out error if result is not found by api in external database?

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to show a div with "No city found" if a city is not in external database.

How is this possible?

```
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
} 

if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $urlContents = curl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$_GET['q']."&type=accurate&units=metric&appid=4802fab0dfe2bf3e1f47e0882a5e93de"); // pre tahanie udajov potrebujeme vlastne app id ktore nam vygeneruje po registracii na stranke https://openweathermap.org/api

    $city = $_GET['q'];

    $weatherArray = json_decode($urlContents, true);

    $weather = $weatherArray['weather'][0]['description'];

    $temp = $weatherArray['main']['temp']; 

    $icon = $weatherArray['weather'][0]['icon'];

    $logo = "<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/".$icon.".png'>";
}
```

Comment: Well, can you share the response when you put a "garbage" city into the url?  please `var_export($weatherArray);` for us.

Comment: its already working, it was some undefined index

Answer (score 1):

You should get a response of

```
{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}
```

from the API if it doesn't find the city in your request, so you could process the response something like...

```
$weatherArray = json_decode($urlContents, true);
if ( isset($weatherArray['cod']) && $weatherArray['cod'] == "404" ) {
    $message = "No city found";
}
else    {
    // Process weather data
}
```

Comment: thank you , its working :)  $weatherArray = json_decode($urlContents, true);
        
if ( isset($weatherArray['cod']) && $weatherArray['cod'] == "404" ) {
    header ("Location:notfound.php");
   
    exit;
} else {
         
        //  process data
         
    }